# Install django db log

Tags: python, django

I tried to install django db log from here https://github.com/dcramer/django-db-log, by running `python setup.py install`, but for some reason when I add the app to the settings.py file, it's not working. here's the error that I get:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

cannot import name Paginator

Exception Location:     /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.1
Python Path:    

['/Users/christopherfarm/Desktop/ecomstore',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.6.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django_db_log-2.2.1-py2.6.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode']

Server time:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the django-db-log's project page:

```
This project is no longer updated. Please see http://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry for its successor
```

So I simply assume that this project is not compatible with Django-1.3.1 due to various deprecations...

Comment: is there no way i can still install it?

Comment: @cfarm54: Either use older Django version or try to fix it so it works with newer Django. But still, I think you should try out django-sentry instead. And you could also ask the author what were the reasons this project was abandoned.